# Com error 10010 Windows task scheduler run even when user is not logged on (win32com.client)

Tags: python, windows, com, scheduled-tasks, win32com

I'm trying to schedule a Python script that uses the win32com.client api. When I schedule it in Windows task scheduler without selecting "run even when user is not logged on" everything works fine. However, when I select that option, the task fails every time (error: 0x1). I checked the Windows event log and I get a "The server {CSID} did not register within the required timeout" (where CSID is a registry key that I've seen corresponds to Outlook).

I'm running Windows Server 2012.

I've already given the user that runs the job the highest permissions in "Component Services".

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So system told you "You don't register your app(CLSID), i am waiting some period but no change !". Probably solution "you need register your app/service if want use some COM objects."

Comment: @dsgdfg Yes, but how?